# Pdf creation Suggestions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, pdf-generation

I have a small web application based on asp.net 2010 that manages invoices.

After the invoice is saved, it should automatically generate a pdf file.

which of the following solutions would be fast and easy to incorporate?

1. Use Sql Server 2008 Reports
2. Use Crystal Reports 2008 and Crystal Reports 2008 for VS 2010
3. Use itextsharp to create the pdf file
4. Use XSLFO to create the pdf file

The point here is I dont know any of the above. Which one is easy and quick to learn and implement. Are there any other solution to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer iTextSharp as it is very flexible as you build the PDF from code as you need it. However as it is a port of the iText open source java library for PDF it is not 100% intuitive (well from a c# perspective)..

However said there are a lot of help blogs and articles.

I have found:-

1. SQL server 2008 needs a lot of configuration and does not quite give you what you want.
2. You need to purchase Crystal Reports, however said it is quite a good product
3. iTextSharp - Free, fairly easy to set up but not 100% intuitive
4. I have used this and found it tough going although it is possible to get the desired ouput.

**edit**

For question regarding VS2010, I used it with VS2005 a number of years ago as the basic version  came shipped with VS2005. According to the [website](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) it appears to integrate into Visual Studio 2010, however this I suspect depends on what version you have.

> SAP Crystal Reports can open and edit
>   files created with SAP Crystal
>   Reports, version for Visual Studio
>   2010 (and vice-versa), providing a
>   fuller set of report design features
>   compared to SAP Crystal Reports,
>   version for Visual Studio 2010. SAP
>   Crystal Reports does not include
>   tooling to support the Visual Studio
>   2010 development environment but
>   developers can use the SAP Crystal
>   Reports, version for Visual Studio
>   2010 runtime engine to deploy SAP
>   Crystal Reports RPT files with all the
>   extended design features.

Comment: Hi Rippo. thank you so much for the answer. I already have a purchased version of crystal reports. How easy it is to integrate it with asp.net 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The first two options sound a bit heavyweight for your requirements.

You don't say if you require it to be free (open source) or if you are happy to pay for a solution; a quick search found this: [ExpertPDF HtmlToPdf Converter](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/)

I have to admit that I have never used it but it might be an easy solution if you are already displaying the invoice on your web page.

Comment: Hi Tony,Thanks for the answer. But we are not interested to buy anything new. we arleady have sql server 2008 and crystal reports 2008 purchased.

Comment: Fair enough. If you have SQL Server reporting services then you can use that to generate more than just PDFs. If you need to create Excel sheets from the same orders then you can easily do so; however I'm not sure it fits with your "..fast and easy to incorporate" requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for XSL-FO as it is open standard and you are not being locked in a proprietary solution. You also have access to [visual XSL-FO editors/designers](http://www.ecrion.com/Products/XFDesigner/Overview.aspx) and 3 or 4 high volume server to choose from.

As far as I know, many invoicing statements solutions today use XSL-FO becuse it is very powerful - you can footnotes or very complex pagination, 10-20 output formats, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i have done something similar with XSLFO - if you know XSLT then XSLFO is very simple to add to XSLT

Comment: Thanks Paul. I dont know XSLT and XSLFO. How easy is this to learn to build a simple invoice pdf with 2 pages.

Comment: If you dont know XSLT then it will take slightly longer - but XSLT is pretty easy to do simple things - have a google and see what you think of the syntax and structure before you tie yourself to a specific method

Comment: Hi Paul. Can you tell me what is the component you used in C# to create teh pdf using xslfo?

Comment: this is the product i used http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_to_pdf.html - there is some basic syntax on that page as well

Answer (score 0):

For me, using [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) with the [mailmerge feature](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/index.html) was always the fastest and most flexible/comfortable solution, although not the cheapest.

Answer (score 0):

The super simple way is use third party converter such as ABCPdf, Winnovative PDF Converter. But they cost abount $500 USD.
You said you bought Crystal Report, it can use to generate pdf as well, just use Crystal Report design the pdf template, connect to your database (dataset,datatables). In your code to push data from your database and fill the pdf template finally save as pdf.
But deploy Crystal Report you need merge some modules, otherwise you need install Crystal Report on your server as well.